# Is there an easy way to make an horizontal single stacked Barplot with R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, percentage, stacked

I'd appreciate it if anyone could help me with making a single stacked Barplot with R. Here is a small example of data to plot:

```
cell_type   Percentage
CD20 B cells    15.00
CD4 T cells 25.00
Other cells 60.00
```

This is what I used, but cannot modify it too much.

```
p1 <-  ggplot(Data, aes(x = "", y = percentage, fill = cell_type))

p1

p2 <-  p1 + geom_col()
p2
```

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: what are you trying to modify? Your code works fine to create a stacked bar chart.

Comment: I wanted to change the width and the colours. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(dummy = "v") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = dummy, y = Percentage, fill = cell_type)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(Percentage, "%")),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(x = "", y = "Percentage")
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Use `coord_flip` to make it horizontal, to adjust bar thickness specify the `width` argument, and you can set fill colors manually using `scale_fill_manual`:

```
library(ggplot2)

df %>%  
  ggplot(aes(x = "", y = Percentage, fill = cell_type)) + 
  geom_col(width = .25) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("black", "#039dfc", "yellow")) + 
  coord_flip()
```

If you have multiple bars then you will need to set an x-axis variable.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**
x-axis:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

my_matrix <- df %>% 
  column_to_rownames("cell_type") %>% 
  rename(Cells = Percentage) %>% 
  as.matrix()

my_Matrix <- apply(my_matrix, 2, cumsum)
my_Matrix <- my_Matrix - my_matrix / 2


par(mfrow = c(1, 3))
x <- barplot(my_matrix,
             ylab = "Percentage",
             col=c("red2", "green3", "slateblue4"),
             border="white",
             legend.text = rownames(my_matrix),
             args.legend=list(cex=1,x = "topright"))


text(rep(x, each = nrow(my_Matrix)), my_Matrix, cex = 1.5, col = "white", labels = paste0(Percentage, "%"))
```

[image]

**First answer:**

Here is a **base R barplot**: as an alternative approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

my_matrix <- df %>% 
  column_to_rownames("cell_type") %>% 
  as.matrix()

my_Matrix <- apply(my_matrix, 2, cumsum)
my_Matrix <- my_Matrix - my_matrix / 2


par(mfrow = c(1, 3))
x <- barplot(my_matrix,
        col=c("red2", "green3", "slateblue4"),
        border="white",
       # col = 1 + 1:nrow(my_matrix),
        width = 0.5,
        legend.text = rownames(my_matrix),
        args.legend=list(cex=1,x = "topright"))

text(rep(x, each = nrow(my_Matrix)), my_Matrix, cex = 1.5, col = "white", labels = paste0(Percentage, "%"))
```

[image]

Comment: Percentage should be the y-axis.

Comment: Thank you for this important info. Please see my update!